# Как пройтись по списку и выдать подряд повторяющие строки python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дали задание сделать примитивный DDOS сканер, в него подаётся список IP адресов и программа должна выдать только те что идут подряд n'ое кол-во раз

```html
      Ввод                      Вывод 
    '4',                        192.168.1.1
    '3',                        192.168.1.4 
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.3',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.3',
    '192.168.1.4',
    '192.168.1.4',
    '192.168.1.4',
```

не могу реализовать как пройтись с помощью регулярных по списку и вывести только те что повторяются подряд

Comment: На данный момент вот что я сделал :
1- Запустил цикл `for val in m:`  где с помощью регулярных выражений выбираю только IP адреса `if re.findall(r'\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{1}.\d{1}',val):`  далее их добавляю в новый массив `ad.append(val) ` как теперь из этого массива выбрать только те что идут подряд ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, зачем вам регулярные выражения, потому как вопрос решить можно так:

```
import itertools

a = ['4',
    '3',
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.3',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.3',
    '192.168.1.4',
    '192.168.1.4',
    '192.168.1.4',]

for (key,group) in itertools.groupby(a): 
    if len(list(group))>1:
        print (key)
```

Получим:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью словаря:

```
m = {}

for string in input:
    if m.get(string):
        m[string] += 1
    else:
        m[string] = 1

for string in m:
    if m.get(string) > 1:
        print(string)
```

Comment: А ключом в словаре что будет ?  те ip что я вписал это пример , надо через input().split().

Comment: @АнастасСмех ключом как раз будет ip, если он встречается больше одного раза, то в значение с повторяющимся ключом будет больше 1

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Comment: В данном решении не выполняется требование "идут подряд", счётчик считает всё неважно в каком порядке